# The following SQL code throws error

Tags: sql, join, group-by

```
    SELECT fp.Physician_Key,
       fp.Month,
       pd.DisplayName,
       hd.ProductName,
       SUM(AmtPaid) AS TotalCost
FROM F_ProgramCost_Fact fp
INNER JOIN D_HEALTHPLANDim hd ON hd.HealthPlan_Key = fp.HealthPlan_Key
INNER JOIN D_PHYSICIANDim pd ON fp.Physician_Key = fp.Physician_Key
INNER JOIN F_MemberPatient_FactLess mpf ON fp.MemberPatientFact_Key = mpf.MemberPatientFact_Key
GROUP BY fp.Physician_Key
```

Getting this error "Column 'F_ProgramCost_Fact.Month' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Please help! 
Thanks

Comment: As you're `SUM`ming, how you're expecting SQL engine to hangle different values for `F_ProgramCost_Fact.Month` column?
And what about the other columns?
You have to add them to `GROUP BY` so that you will get the `SUM` by each combination of other columns.

Answer (score 0):

you need to group by all the columns:

```
select fp.Physician_Key,fp.Month,pd.DisplayName,hd.ProductName,SUM(AmtPaid) as TotalCost
From F_ProgramCost_Fact fp
Inner Join D_HEALTHPLANDim hd
ON hd.HealthPlan_Key = fp.HealthPlan_Key
Inner join D_PHYSICIANDim pd
ON fp.Physician_Key = fp.Physician_Key 
Inner Join F_MemberPatient_FactLess mpf ON fp.MemberPatientFact_Key = mpf.MemberPatientFact_Key
Group By fp.Physician_Key,fp.Month,pd.DisplayName,hd.ProductName
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!